# after installing odoo12 community I am getting Import error

Tags: odoo, python-3.5, odoo-12

After installing Odoo 12 Community in Ubuntu 16.04 from https://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/installing-odoo-12-enterprise-ubuntu/

I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoodev/NewOdoo12e/odoo_12.0+e.latest_all/data/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo-bin", line 5, in <module>
    import odoo
  File "/home/odoodev/NewOdoo12e/odoo_12.0+e.latest_all/data/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from . import modules
  File "/home/odoodev/NewOdoo12e/odoo_12.0+e.latest_all/data/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
  File "/home/odoodev/NewOdoo12e/odoo_12.0+e.latest_all/data/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 10, in <module>
    import odoo.tools as tools
  File "/home/odoodev/NewOdoo12e/odoo_12.0+e.latest_all/data/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .config import config
  File "/home/odoodev/NewOdoo12e/odoo_12.0+e.latest_all/data/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/tools/config.py", line 18, in <module>
    from passlib.context import CryptContext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/passlib/context.py", line 20, in <module>
    from passlib.registry import get_crypt_handler, _validate_handler_name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/passlib/registry.py", line 11, in <module>
    from passlib.utils import is_crypt_handler
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/passlib/utils/__init__.py", line 32, in <module>
    from passlib.utils.compat import add_doc, b, bytes, join_bytes, join_byte_values, \
ImportError: cannot import name 'b'
```

I already have Odoo 12 Enterprise version, but after installing Odoo 12 Community, getting same error in Odoo 12 Enterprise.

Comment: if i am not wrong your documentation is not for community version!!!

Comment: Is there any custom modules are there ?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this.

```
sudo pip3 install passlib==1.6.5

sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip

sudo -H pip3 install pipenv
```

Comment: Thanks! Only "sudo pip3 install passlib==1.6.5"  solved the issue!!

Comment: If this answer solve your problem then mark it for other users